# Failed to install ZAP_2.4.2_Core.tar.gz

Tags: jenkins, installation, owasp, zap

it's my first post here so please excuse me for making any mistakes.

I try to perform the installation of ZAProxy Plugin in Jenkins.

I installed the custom tools plugin by inserting the values according to the website https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZAProxy+Plugin.

After that I execute ZAProxy in my Jenkins Job:

[image: my job configuration]

After performing the build I see the following error:

```
Perform ZAProxy
Unpacking https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads/ZAP_2.4.3_Core.tar.gz to /var/lib/jenkins/tools/com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool/ZAProxy_2.4.3 on Jenkins
ERROR: java.io.IOException: Failed to install https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads/ZAP_2.4.3_Core.tar.gz to /var/lib/jenkins/tools/com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool/ZAProxy_2.4.3
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:832)
    at hudson.tools.ZipExtractionInstaller.performInstallation(ZipExtractionInstaller.java:79)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:108)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool.forNode(CustomTool.java:154)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool.forNode(CustomTool.java:59)
    at fr.novia.zaproxyplugin.ZAProxy.retrieveZapHomeWithToolInstall(ZAProxy.java:486)
    at fr.novia.zaproxyplugin.ZAProxy.checkParams(ZAProxy.java:574)
    at fr.novia.zaproxyplugin.ZAProxy.startZAP(ZAProxy.java:613)
    at fr.novia.zaproxyplugin.ZAProxyBuilder.perform(ZAProxyBuilder.java:159)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:919)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:870)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to unpack https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads/ZAP_2.4.3_Core.tar.gz (26 bytes read of total -1)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:826)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to extract input stream
    at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2300)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$400(FilePath.java:190)
    at hudson.FilePath$10.invoke(FilePath.java:720)
    at hudson.FilePath$10.invoke(FilePath.java:718)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at hudson.FilePath.untarFrom(FilePath.java:718)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:824)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
    at com.jcraft.jzlib.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:134)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.readRecord(TarArchiveInputStream.java:419)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.getRecord(TarArchiveInputStream.java:388)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.getNextTarEntry(TarArchiveInputStream.java:269)
    at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2278)
    ... 26 more

Build step 'Execute ZAProxy' marked build as failure
[DependencyCheck] Collecting Dependency-Check analysis files...
[DependencyCheck] Finding all files that match the pattern dependency-check- report.xml
[DependencyCheck] Parsing 1 file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<project name>_continuous/workspace
[DependencyCheck] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<project name>_continuous/workspace/dependency-check-report.xml of module <company name> HELP with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
[DependencyCheck] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #75
[DependencyCheck] Ignore new warnings since this is the first valid build
[DependencyCheck] Plug-in Result: Success - no threshold has been exceeded
Finished: FAILURE
```

I just couldn*t find any information about this error(s) and I'm sure it could help other newcomers who have to use this plugin in the future. Please help me. It's the Jenkins of my company so I have to conceal internal information. I overdraw it for you with red color.

Comment: If I visit [ZAP_2.4.2_Core.tar.gz at github](https://github.com/cvdsouza/files-for-fun/blob/master/ZAP_2.4.2_Core.tar.gz) I see this: *(Sorry about that, but we can’t show files that are this big right now.)* that explains why you get this error

Comment: Hi Rene, thanks for your comment. I changed the download link in jenkins configuration to https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads/ZAP_2.4.3_Core.tar.gz. The link seems to work but build fails with the same error.

Comment: Do you have any further idea?

Comment: No, I have not, except trying to figure out why it wants to download that file Maybe you can host it your self instead.

Comment: We solved it by bringing the zap.sh into the system manually, where I now try to trigger the batch script manually. There has been a war between me and the Xvfb-plugin, the display variable and a stopping script. But this could be a topic for another question in the future, we'll see about that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get that URL from?

The correct one for ZAP 2.4.3 core is: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/releases/download/2.4.3/ZAP_2.4.3_Core.tar.gz

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. It has been a too long time. I only can say that there have been a long web search and a lot of not working links until I found the link.

Comment: Strange. The ZAP OWASP and github pages have big 'Download' buttons that point to https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads
That has links to all of the latest ZAP packages including the core one.